# Sum of points per user greater than some value and ordered

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this should be easy but it's just not my day today.

I have a table like this

```
user     |  points     
---------|------------
Smith    |    100
Neo      |    200
Morpheus |    300
Smith    |    100
Neo      |    200
Morpheus |    300
```

and the select I'm looking for would produce this

```
user     |  points     
---------|------------
Morpheus |    600
Neo      |    400
```

So, I would like to print out the users who have more than 300 points total and i would like to print them out sorted by sum from highest to lowest.

I'm using:

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.61, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

The SQL I've been trying is this:

```
SELECT user, SUM(points) AS sum FROM users GROUP BY user HAVING SUM(points)>300
```

and this gives me all the correct output, though it doesn't give me sorted output. And I did try inserting the ORDER BY but to no luck.

Comment: It works on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad67d/2).  What's the problem with `ORDER BY`?  What results are you getting when you add that clause?

Comment: as i said, bad day, i could swear i tried it the way @juergen  replied but seems i haven't - his answer will be marked as correct after the minimum time for acceptance passes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT user, SUM(points) AS sum 
FROM users 
GROUP BY user 
HAVING sum > 300
order by sum desc
```

Comment: Is this really true?  The "having sum(points) > 300" is standard SQL syntax.  I would have thought that mysql would support that.

Comment: Mysql supports both: `having sum(points) > 300` and `having sum > 300`

Answer (score 0):

Should just be

```
SELECT user, SUM(points) AS sum FROM users GROUP BY user HAVING SUM(points)>300 
ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC
```

unless I'm missing something